# Invalid MEX-file is not a valid shared library, fftw libraries

Tags: c++, matlab, libraries, fftw

I have a problem with the following code. The compilation of the .mex file is done, but when I try to run it from the matlab script , I receive an error like

Invalid MEX-file
'myfile.mexa64':
'myfile.mexa64' is not a valid shared library..

```
    mex CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fopenmp -m64 -Ofast -fPIC --fast-math" ...
    CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -fopenmp -m64 -Ofast -fPIC --fast-math" ...
    LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp" ...
    CXXOPTIMFLAGS="$CXXOPTIMFLAGS -fopenmp" ...
    -lgomp -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 Fourier_CPU.cpp

    n_1 = 100; n_2 = 100; n_3 = 100;

    A = rand(n_1,n_2,n_3) + 1i*rand(n_1,n_2,n_3);

    fc = @() Fourier_CPU(A,n_1,n_2,n_3);
    B = fc();
```

The Fourier_CPU file is the .cpp file that calls some fftw functions. I NOTE that the code works correctly when I am running it on my laptop by gives the error above when I run it on a server. 
I think that this have to do something with the libraries linking, but I am not sure what's the problem. 
Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I assume there is a shared library that is in your laptop that code is linked to, and when moved to the sever, it can not find it (or something like that, I have no idea about this sutff)

Comment: Probably it's fftw3_omp and fftw3. If I remove these two sneaky guys and comment out the fftw functions in the .cpp files the code runs.

Comment: Can't you somehow deploy those with the mex file?

Comment: I don't know how unfortunately